# The function CreateWICTextureFromFile() will not actually load a texture (Direct3D11, C++)

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct3d11

I am trying to load a grass texture onto my game with the function `DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromFile` but everytime I do, the function won't seem to actually load anything, it just loads a black texture. The function successfully returns `S_OK`, and i've also called the `CoInitialize(NULL)` before I actually call the function. But it still doesn't work.

Down below is my usage of the function

```
// This is where i load the texture
void Load_Texture_for_Ground()
{
HRESULT status;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView * Texture;

CoInitialize(NULL);

status = DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromFile(device, L"AmazingGrass.jpg", NULL, &Texture);

if (Texture != NULL)    // This returns true
{
    MessageBox(MainWindow, L"The pointer points to the texture", L"MessageBox", MB_OK);
}

if (status == S_OK)   //This returns true
{
    MessageBox(MainWindow, L"The function succeeded", L"MessageBox", MB_OK);
}

CoUninitialize();
}

// This is where i actually load the texture onto an object, assuming i already declared all the variables in this function
void DrawTheGround ()
{

DevContext->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0);      

DevContext->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);  

DevContext->IASetVertexBuffers(
                            0,                  
                            1,                  
                            &GroundVertexBuffer,
                            &strides,           
                            &offset             
                            );
DevContext->IASetIndexBuffer(
                        IndexBuffer,            
                        DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 
                        0
                        );

        /* Transforming the matrices*/
TransformedMatrix = GroundWorld * CameraView * CameraProjection ;

Data.WORLDSPACE = XMMatrixTranspose(GroundWorld);

Data.TRANSFORMEDMATRIX = XMMatrixTranspose(TransformedMatrix);

        /* Updating the matrix in application's Constant Buffer*/
DevContext->UpdateSubresource(
                        ConstantBuffer,                 
                        0,                              
                        NULL,                           
                        &Data,                          
                        0,                              
                        0                               
                        );

DevContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &ConstantBuffer);

DevContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &Texture);

DevContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &TextureSamplerState);

DevContext->DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0);

}
```

What could be wrong here? Why won't the function load the texture?

Comment: you should call CoInitialize(NULL); at the start of your application , and CoUninitialize at the end

Comment: It still won't make a difference, the function still loads nothing

Comment: Can you send a link to your jpg file? I'd like to try to repro your issue. Can you show the source for building ``GroundVertexBuffer``. Also, you should as marcinj notes call ``CoInitialize`` at the start of your application, not at the start of the function.

Comment: Its ok. I found the problem. It seems that something is wrong with my pixel shaders. The lighting calculations were incorrect.

Comment: Note that ``status == S_OK`` is not valid COM. You need to use ``SUCCEEDED(status)`` or ``FAILED(status)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to test if you have loaded the texture data correctly is to use `SaveWICTextureToFile` in the [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ScreenGrab) module right after loading it. You'd only do this for debugging of course.

```
#include <wincodec.h>
#include <wrl/cient.h>
using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> Res;
ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> Texture;
HRESULT status = DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromFile(device, L"AmazingGrass.jpg", &Res, &Texture);

if (FAILED(status))
    // Error handling

#ifdef _DEBUG
    status = SaveWICTextureToFile( DevContext, Res.Get(),
                GUID_ContainerFormatBmp, L"SCREENSHOT.BMP" );
#endif
```

Then you can run the code and check that `SCREENSHOT.BMP` is not all black.

> I strongly suggest you adopt the [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) smart pointer and the `FAILED` / `SUCCEEDED` macros in your coding style. Raw pointers and directly comparing `HRESULT` to `S_OK` is setting yourself up for a lot of bugs.

You should not call `CoInitialize` every frame. You should call it once as part of your application's initialization.

You should not be creating a new instance of `SpriteBatch` and `SpriteFont` every frame. Just create them after you create your device and hold on to them.